# These bits of code all have errors in how can i fix this?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, syntax-error

This has an error next to `VARCHAR2` and `(4)`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Employee_exists
 (p_employee_id IN NUMBER)
RETURN VARCHAR2(4);
AS
BEGIN
        SELECT employee_id
        FROM employees
        WHERE employee_id = p_employee_id;

        RETURN 'true';

END Employee_exists;
```

Here it says there is an error next to the decleration of `v_years_service`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Calculate_Bonus(p_salary IN NUMBER, p_startdate IN DATE)
RETURN NUMBER -- here it errors
AS
  v_years_service NUMBER;
BEGIN

  v_years_service := TRUNC(Months_Between(SYSDATE, v_startdate) /12);

  IF (v_years_service <2) THEN
        p_bonus := v_salary * 0.02;
  ELSE 
  IF (v_year_service <2) THEN
        p_bonus := v_salary * 0.04;
  ELSE
        p_bonus := v_salary * 0.05;

  RETURN p_bonus;
END IF;
END Calculate_Bonus;
/

show err
```

Comment: In your second block of code the last else statement will never get hit since the first two if statements take care of all valid values. First being anything less then 2 and the second being anything greater then or equal to 2 leaving nothing left for the last else statement.

Answer (score 1):

For the `Employee_exists` function, change this:

```
RETURN VARCHAR2(4)
```

To this:

```
RETURN VARCHAR
```

For the `Calculate_bonus` function, move this line...

```
v_years_service NUMBER;
```

... so it's under the `AS` line:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Calculate_bonus(p_salary IN NUMBER, p_startdate IN DATE)
RETURN NUMBER
AS
  v_years_service NUMBER; --here is where the error appears
BEGIN
  ... and the rest
```

Finally, there's this line:

```
v_years_service = TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, v_startdate) /12);
```

The variable assignment is always `:=`, so change it to this:

```
v_years_service := TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, v_startdate) /12);
```

---

**Addendum A** Also note the comment from @JoeW under your question. Joe states - correctly - that your `ELSE` condition will never be hit.

---

**Addendum B**

Here's the full function. You may also want to round the return value, as a salary multiplied by 0.02 or 0.05 can give fractional cents. To round, substitute `RETURN ROUND(p_bonus, 2);` for `RETURN p_bonus;`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Calculate_Bonus(p_salary IN NUMBER, p_startdate IN DATE)
RETURN NUMBER
AS
  v_years_service NUMBER;
  v_bonus NUMBER;
BEGIN
  v_years_service := TRUNC(Months_Between(SYSDATE, p_startdate) /12);
  IF (v_years_service <2) THEN
        v_bonus := p_salary * 0.02;
  ELSE
        v_bonus := p_salary * 0.05;
  END IF;
  RETURN v_bonus;
END Calculate_Bonus;
/
```

Comment: Thank you but when i do this it now errors after RETURN NUMBER line 2 and it says the ending should be replaced with an if see above code for the changes i made

Comment: on the task 2 part of code

Comment: Your new code has a lot of errors: the variables `p_startdate` and `p_salary` are defined in the parameter list, but later on you reference `v_salary` and `v_startdate` - these should start with `p_`, not `v_`. You have two `IF` statements gone haywire, and you don't declare the `p_bonus` variable. See my updated answer. My advice is relax and try to be more careful and deliberate when writing functions. Start with a stub and add on gradually, fixing errors as you go, and you'll have this mastered in no time :)