# In Pl Sql I encounter and error encountered the symbol "CALCULATE_BONUS"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, syntax-error

The error seems to occur with the end statement all though i cannot for the life of me find out what it is I am sure it will be something silly.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Calculate_Bonus(p_salary IN NUMBER, p_startdate IN DATE)
RETURN NUMBER IS
  v_years_service NUMBER;
BEGIN
  v_years_service := TRUNC(Months_Between(SYSDATE, v_startdate) /12);

  IF (v_years_service <2) THEN
        p_bonus := v_salary * 0.02;
  ELSE 
  IF (v_year_service >=2) THEN
        p_bonus := v_salary * 0.04;
  ELSE
        p_bonus := v_salary * 0.05;

  RETURN p_bonus;
END IF;
END Calculate_Bonus;
/
show err
```

Comment: Syntax error, please check `if-then-else` syntax from [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/controlstatements.htm).

Comment: Streetrun - please see the answer I updated for your last question. Also note that your logic in this latest version makes no sense: you check for years<2, then years>=2, then "else". When you check for <2 or >=2 *there is no else*. Finally, the `RETURN p_bonus` will only be executed for the `ELSE` condition. Even after you fix the logic, you want to return *after* the `END IF`.

Comment: Sorry Streetrun - meant to leave a link to the answer. It's [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19140864/2091410)

Comment: possible duplicate of [These bits of code all have errors in how can i fix this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140714/these-bits-of-code-all-have-errors-in-how-can-i-fix-this)

Comment: Thank you but i have done all you have asked and it is still erroring

Comment: @EdGibbs, technically there *can be* an "else". If years is null, then neither the years<2 and years>=2 conditions will be true.

Comment: Thanks @JeffreyKemp - absolutely correct, and I really do know better :) I agree with you using "technically" too, because a 5% bonus for unknown hire date sounds iffy.

Answer (score 2):

You've been directed to check the if-else-end syntax, but your question still shows that you have nested `IF` blocks with a missing `END IF`. Indented to hopefully show the problem:

```
...
  IF (v_years_service <2) THEN
    p_bonus := v_salary * 0.02;
  ELSE 
    IF (v_year_service >=2) THEN
      p_bonus := v_salary * 0.04;
    ELSE
      p_bonus := v_salary * 0.05;
      RETURN p_bonus;
    END IF;
END Calculate_Bonus;
```

You have two opening `IF` keywords but only one `END IF`. So when it gets to the `END Calculate_Bonus` line it isn't expecting to see the end of the function, because the outer `IF` block hasn't been closed. So you'd need to do this (with the `return` moved as Ed also pointed out):

```
...
  IF (v_years_service <2) THEN
    p_bonus := v_salary * 0.02;
  ELSE 
    IF (v_year_service >=2) THEN
      p_bonus := v_salary * 0.04;
    ELSE
      p_bonus := v_salary * 0.05;
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN p_bonus;
END Calculate_Bonus;
```

You could also use `ELSIF` rather than a nested `IF`:

```
...
  IF (v_years_service <2) THEN
    p_bonus := v_salary * 0.02;
  ELSIF (v_year_service >=2) THEN
    p_bonus := v_salary * 0.04;
  ELSE
    p_bonus := v_salary * 0.05;
  END IF;
  RETURN p_bonus;
END Calculate_Bonus;
```

I'm ignoring that the e`else` is unreachable, because you've already been told that too, and this shows what to do if you did have a scenario that made it valid, say if the second teir is supposed to be for service years between 2 and 5, or something - in which case the second condition is missing an `and`...

Or you could even do:

```
...
  p_bonus := v_salary * CASE WHEN v_years_service < 2 THEN 0.02
    WHEN v_years_service >= 2 THEN 0.04
    ELSE 0.05 END;
  RETURN p_bonus;
END Calculate_Bonus;
```

You really need to clarify whether your second condition is missing an upper bound though.